# present top viewcontroller above tabbarcontroller within navcontroller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have a setup question on viewcontroller stacking.
I have an app with a tabbar controller. Each tab page needs a navbar, provided by a navcontroller in each tab and within the content. No problem there.
However, I need to present a viewcontroller above the tabbar, above the tabs.
I cant presentviewcontroler on a tabbarcontroller(which is not a navcon) and I cant use the navcons inside the tabcon, as the tabs would sit on top.

So I put a navcon as main container, I put the tabbarcon inside of that.
the viewcon to present now sits on top of everything, but the only remaining issue is, that the main container navcon's navbar covers the navbars inside the tabbarcon's navcons and I need the header on the topmost viewcon, that sits above everything.

Has anyone a slicker solution for this apart from switching the navbar of the main container navcon on and off whenever I present a view controller on top of everything?

Answer (score 0):

I defined a property in AppDelegate

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController* rootNavController;
```

which i could use to present a viewController over the TabBar using the delegate object method like

```
        self.navController = nil;

        LGLoginViewController* loginView = [[LGLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LGLoginViewController"bundle:nil];

        if (!self.navController) {
            self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginView];
        } else {
            [self.navController initWithRootViewController:loginView];
        }

        self.navController.delegate = self;
        [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:self.navController animated:NO];
```

and later on i dismiss the controller

Comment: Yes, that's a similar setup I have, if not the same. It does not, however offer a smarter solution that tackles two things: 1) be able to present a viewcon with navbar on top of tabbarcon   2) not have that navbar cover the navcons' navbars within the tabbarcon.   Your solution does 1), but doesnt explain 2)

Comment: I think presentModalViewController is also outdated as of iOS7

Comment: i think your second point is not making sense to me, why do you need that kinda setup?

Comment: Retro: the main navcon's navbar is covering the navbar's of the navcons withing the tabbarcon. That is obviously an issue. What part doesn't make sense?

Comment: if there is any action which you want to perform then from your presented modelViewController you can create the same kinda header with nav button.

Comment: Retro: I don't understand what you last comment means. The within tabbarcons navcons are related to the viewcons they control. those viewcons can't use the main navcon navbar, can they? That would be a less than pretty wiring solution.

Comment: The action could be trigger based notifications or delegates and action could be handle based on selected tab index